# Run a query per N number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a production environment and I need to run this code and append to table `[RESULTS_TABLE]`, let's say, for each 10K lines `FROM TABLE [SOURCETABLE]`. How do I do this? (due to system and memory limitations I need to do this).

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[RESULTS_TABLE]') AND type IN (N'U'))
        DROP TABLE [RESULTS_TABLE]

    CREATE TABLE [RESULTS_TABLE](
    [CLAIM_ID] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [CIN] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [SVC_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [SVC_DATE_TO] [datetime] NULL,
    [TOTAL_DAYS] [int] NULL,
    [CHAIN_COUNT] [int] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    ;WITH chain_builder AS
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.CIN, s.CLAIM_ID) as chain_ID,
      s.CIN,
      s.SVC_DATE, s.SVC_DATE_TO, s.CLAIM_ID, 1 as chain_count
    FROM [SOURCETABLE] s
    WHERE s.SVC_DATE <> ALL 
      (
      SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, s2.SVC_DATE_TO)
      FROM [SOURCETABLE] s2
      WHERE s.CIN = s2.CIN
      )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT chain_ID, s.CIN, s.SVC_DATE, s.SVC_DATE_TO,
      s.CLAIM_ID, chain_count + 1
      FROM [SOURCETABLE] s
    JOIN chain_builder as c
      ON s.CIN = c.CIN AND
      s.SVC_DATE = DATEADD(d, 1, c.SVC_DATE_TO)
    ),
    chains AS
    (
    SELECT chain_ID, CIN, SVC_DATE, SVC_DATE_TO,
      CLAIM_ID, chain_count, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY chain_ID, chain_count ORDER BY SVC_DATE_TO DESC) as link_row
    FROM chain_builder
    ),
    link_picker AS
    (
    SELECT chain_ID, CIN, SVC_DATE, SVC_DATE_TO,
      CLAIM_ID, chain_count
    FROM chains
    WHERE link_row = 1
    ),
    diff AS
    (
    SELECT c.chain_ID, c.CIN, c.SVC_DATE, c.SVC_DATE_TO,
      c.CLAIM_ID, c.chain_count,
      datediff(day,c.SVC_DATE,c.SVC_DATE_TO)+1 daysdiff
    FROM link_picker c
    ),
    diff_sum AS
    (
    SELECT chain_ID, CIN, SVC_DATE, SVC_DATE_TO,
      CLAIM_ID, chain_count,
      SUM(daysdiff) OVER (PARTITION BY chain_ID) as total_diff
    FROM diff
    ),
    diff_comp AS
    (
    SELECT chain_ID, CIN,
      MAX(total_diff) OVER (PARTITION BY CIN) as total_diff
    FROM diff_sum
    )
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[LTAC_TEST_1]
    SELECT DISTINCT ds.CLAIM_ID, ds.CIN, ds.SVC_DATE,
      ds.SVC_DATE_TO, ds.total_diff as TOTAL_DAYS, ds.chain_count as CHAIN_COUNT
    FROM diff_sum ds
    JOIN diff_comp dc
    ON ds.chain_ID = dc.chain_ID AND ds.CIN = dc.CIN
      AND ds.total_diff = dc.total_diff
    OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try creating a stored procedure. In the procedure add your sql but limit the amount of work it does using 'top 10000'. Something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.CIN, s.CLAIM_ID) as chain_ID, ...
```

Then set up an SSIS job to run the stored procedure periodically. If there's more than 10,000 results it will catch the next 10,000 on the next run of the stored procedure.

Comment: how do i select next 10000 records then? how do i loop ?

Comment: Yes, a loop will work well. If you run this repeatedly how are you preventing the process from picking up duplicates? I mostly use a status column that indicates I've already processed a row.

Answer (score 0):

For the next 10000

use

select top 20000...

except

select top 10000...